# How to optimise a slow MySQL table update query?

Tags: mysql, performance

A simple update of one column using primary key in the where clause takes 0.8 seconds to 1.5 seconds. How can I optimize this query?

Update query:

```
UPDATE oc_product SET viewed=(viewed+1) WHERE 
product_id=1521225;
Query OK, 1 row affected (***1.10 sec***)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Explain of the same query

```
explain UPDATE oc_product SET viewed=(viewed+1)        WHERE product_id=1521225;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | oc_product | NULL       | range |  PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the show create table statement output:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `oc_product` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
`isbn` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
`mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`points` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_available` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01',
`weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
`weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
`width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
`height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
`length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
`date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
`maximum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`usps_factor` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`sitemap_file` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`sameday_delivery` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sameday_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1523031 DEFAULT 
 CHARSET =utf8
```

Comment: Why is your default date 1018 years ago? You're better off with `NOT NULL`.

Comment: This could be related to other activity on the server. Is `SHOW PROCESSLIST` busy? Are you using an HDD instead of SSD? Does the same problem manifest on a new table with just `id` and `viewed` columns?

Comment: @tadman, I have removed default value date_available and ran the update query. It still took longer.
SHOW PROCESS LIST is not busy. This is on our dev server which is hosted on AWS. Found this issue on Production server in slow query logs. I replicated the same in dev environment.

Are you using an HDD instead of SSD?
We are using aws m4-large instance for database server. The other updates are fine. Issue is with only oc_product table update. no matter what field is updated on the table, it takes on average 1 sec. Other update queries on other tables are executed in milli seconds.

Comment: You're going to have to try and reproduce this problem in another table and/or on another physical system to narrow down the scope of it. From the look of things that's a lot of irrelevant data, but it's a fairly large row in a table that looks like it's thoroughly populated. Adjusting a single number should be fast, especially one that isn't indexed. If it isn't there's got to be a reason.

Comment: For example, if you use RDS does the problem manifest? Does it run slowly on your local machine with the same number of records on the production system? You need to exclude all potential causes until you find the actual cause.

Comment: I have created another temp table "viewed" with only product_id & viewed columns. Update on this new table is fast.

UPDATE viewed SET viewed=(viewed+1) WHERE product_id=1521225;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `viewed` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1521226 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Try filling it up with a few million records, and from there, add more columns until you notice the slow down.

Comment: I see nothing obvious.  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'oc_product';`  If there are any `TRIGGERs`, please show them.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any long running query on oc_product table?
Create a copy of oc_product table and run update query on new table.